# Update mongo values

Tags: python, mongodb

Hi I am trying to update values in my database. I have the following data:

```
{'_id': 123,
 'keys': 
  {'values': 
    {'value1': 1,
     'value2: 2,
    }
{
```

I am trying to update the values with the following query:

```py
new_values = {'value3': 3,
              'value4': 4}
col.update_one({'_id': 123},{"$set": {"keys": new_values}})
```

Expected result:

```
{'_id': 123,
 'keys': 
  {'values': 
    {'value1': 1,
     'value2': 2,
     'value3': 3,
     'value4': 4,
    }
{
```

Actual result:

```
{'_id': 123,
 'keys': 
  {'values': 
    {'value3': 3,
     'value4': 4,
    }
{
```

What am I missing, should I update it field for field in a loop over the `new_values`?

Comment: `$set` is a full replacement -- the existing values are discarded.

Comment: Check about $push which would add elements instead of replacing elements. By the way your code {"$set": {"keys": new_values}} could not result to what you said. Please check your code first next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to replace the values in key `values` instead of add new sub-keys.

There are two solutions to your problem.

**Solution - 1**

Specify the absolute key naming for each sub-keys in the update command

```
col.update_one({'_id': 123},{"$set": {"keys.values.value3": 3, "keys.values.value4": 4}})
```

**Solution - 2**

Get the existing value by `find_one` command and perform `update_one` operation joining the two dictionaries.

```
new_values = {'value3': 3,
              'value4': 4}

temp = col.find_one({'_id': 123}, {"keys": 1})
dict_to_insert = {**new_values, **temp["keys"]["values"]}

col.update_one({'_id': 123},{"$set": {"keys.values": dict_to_insert}})
```

I would suggest you go with solution 2, although it performs an additional read operation to get it done.